# Whats the difference between add.LSTM(num_hidden, droput=0.5) and add.Dropout(0.5) in Keras?

Tags: keras, lstm, rnn, dropout

Could anyone please explain what is the difference between these two cases, specified in the title.
I believe I am not the only one who is confused.

I have read that it is preferrable to add Dropout separately (second case), but it was not explained why that holds true.

Cheers.

Comment: This can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720670/using-dropout-with-keras-and-lstm-gru-cell

Comment: Thnaks for the link!